# Hallengren @DatabasesInParallel sql_message_id 50000 in sysjobhistory table

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Just implemented Ola's Parallel execution for backups, integrity checks and index maintenance. Everything appears to be running great but I am seeing `sql_message_id 50000` in the `sysjobhistory` table for the new executions. I am also seeing `[SQLSTATE 01000]` on each line of the job output files. Is this normal behavior? I can't seem to find any in-depth documentation online.

Answer (score 3):

**The Message 50000 in msdb.dbo.Sysjobhistory is intended.**

Take part of Ola Hallengren's index optimize procedure:`[dbo].[IndexOptimize]`, part of the integrity checks: `[dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck]`  or part of the backup procedure: `[dbo].[DatabaseBackup]`, the same `RAISERROR()` Statements will be shown:

```
  SET @StartMessage = 'Date and time: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@StartTime,120)
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Server: ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS nvarchar(max))
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Version: ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar(max))
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Edition: ' + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS nvarchar(max))
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Platform: ' + @HostPlatform
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Procedure: ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(DB_ID())) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName)
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Parameters: ' + @Parameters
  SET @StartMessage = REPLACE(@StartMessage,'%','%%')
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Version: ' + @VersionTimestamp
  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT

  SET @StartMessage = 'Source: https://ola.hallengren.com' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' '

  RAISERROR(@StartMessage,10,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

The `RAISERRROR()`'s are going to be executing when the procedure runs.

Looking into the history, we see the 'error's' shown:

```
select message From msdb..sysjobhistory 
where sql_message_id =50000
```

**Result**

```
Executed as user: DOMAIN\test. ...0000)  Server: test [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  Version: 12.0.5546.0 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000) ...
```

With the same Server and Version info as defined in the previous T-SQL examples.

**Why does the 'error' start at 50000?**

It starts at 50000, because starting from 50000 and upwards is where user generated errors can be defined.

**Why are there raiserror()'s in the procedures?**

My opinion is that the `RAISERRROR()` is added to add additional information to the history DMV, as to know what is being executed, and have additional information without it being a mess. It gives you control over what will be shown.

I will leave more in depth reasoning to Ola himself.

Subsequentially the history is added to the SSMS Job Activity monitor that we (Most of us) know and use:
[image]

So to answer the question, it is coded into the proc with reasoning behind it.

---

**RAISERROR() 50000 default example**

You can only generate custom errors with raiserrror when using an error number starting from 50000.

**Testing with a job, with no specific error number:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Starts at 50000.

Comment: This is normal for T-SQL job steps in SQL Server Agent.

Comment: I am using RAISERRROR in the stored procedures to print information about what the stored procedure is doing. I am using RAISERRROR ... WITH NOWAIT instead of PRINT to assure that the text is printed immediately.